# Порядок вывода в List View

Tags: java, android

Есть кастомный адаптер который добавляет строки в лист вью  который до этого не был пустой. Каждую новую строку он добавляет в конец. Подскажите как сделать что бы он добавлял ее в начало?

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("chat");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        UpList.add(new DialogSaveData(
                productObject.getString("id"),
                productObject.getString("avatar"),
                productObject.getString("name"),

                productObject.getString("text"),
                productObject.getString("state")
        ));
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


CastomChat adapter = new CastomChat(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.castom_chat, UpList);
// присваиваем адаптер списку
chatList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Зачем вам listview? Почему не recycler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpList.add(new DialogSaveData(****)); // добавляет в конец массива, вам нужно использовать `UpList.add(0, new DialogSaveData(****));`